# Riemann integrable functions and uniformly convergent.

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $f_n : [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f_n$ is uniformly convergent to $f$

and for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $f_n$ is not Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$

and the question asks whether $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ or not, under these conditions.

I think it's not integrable but I could not prove it, any help or hints ?!

Comment: What if all $f_n$ were identical?

Comment: Your question is not completely clear. Do you choose $f_n$ or is it given?

Comment: Uniform convergence preserves good behavior; it doesn’t necessarily preserve bad behavior. Let $f_n = \tfrac 1 n \chi_{\mathbb Q}$, that is, the Dirichlet function scaled by $1/n$. None of these is Riemann integrable but they converge uniformly to the zero function which is integrable.

Comment: To add to the previous comment if $f$ is not Riemann integrable and bounded what can be said of $f_n=\frac{1}{n} f$ ?

Comment: @User8128 Please consider combining this with David Mitra's idea and post this an answer.

Comment: @User8128 i think that Dirichlet function is Riemann integrable ?!

Comment: @Ahmad the Dirichlet function is very famously not Riemann integrable. It is Lebesgue integrable but it’s continuous nowhere and Riemann integrable functions must be continuous almost everywhere.